# Regex to capture tagged and untagged content

Tags: c#, regex

What I'm wanting to do is to parse some custom tags from a string, but also get the untagged content as well. For example, I have the following string

```
Hello World <Red>This is some red text </Red> This is normal <Blue>This is blue text </Blue>
```

I've got a working regex for getting the tagged content using

```
<(?<tag>\w*)>(?<text>.*)</\k<tag>>
```

However, this returns

```
 tag: Red
 text: This is some red text
 tag: Blue
 text this is blue text
```

What I need is to also get matches for the untagged content, so I would get 4 matches, the two like above and also the "Hello World" and "This is normal".

Is this something that's possible with regex?

For an example this is my current function:

```
 public static List<FormattedConsole> FormatColour(string input)
    {
        List<FormattedConsole> formatted = new List<FormattedConsole>();
        Regex regex = new Regex("<(?<Tag>\\w+)>(?<Text>.*?)</\\1>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
                | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                | RegexOptions.Compiled
        );

        MatchCollection ms = regex.Matches(input);

        foreach (Match match in ms)
        {
            GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
            FormattedConsole format = new FormattedConsole(groups["Text"].Value, groups["Tag"].Value);
            formatted.Add(format);
        }

        return formatted;
    }
```

As mentioned this only returns the matches between the tags. I need to also get the text without tags.

(btw FormattedConsole is simply a container that contains the text and the color)

Comment: How is this related to WPF?

Comment: Is the input XML or does it just look like XML?

Comment: @Clemens Sorry that my fault, I'm used to tagging as WPF because a lot of my questions need different answers because i'm working in WPF. Force of habit.

Comment: @AlexK.It just looks like xml, it's actually just a string sent to a c# function from a lua script. Allowing me to colourise some output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
string sentence = "Hello World <Red>This is some red text </Red> This is normal <Blue>This is blue text </Blue>";
string[] matchSegments = Regex.Split(sentence,@"(<\w+>)(.*?)<\/\w+>");
foreach (string value in matchSegments)
{
    if(value.Contains("<") && value.Contains(">"))
        Console.Write(value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine(value);   
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
<Red>This is some red text
 This is normal
<Blue>This is blue text
```

[Run the code here](http://ideone.com/gp63tU)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess i could use this and then run a second regex on the lines that contain the tag to pull the colour from it. I'll give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: removing the angles will yield the color, just remove the <> inside if condition ... that will do

Comment: Or maybe `@"<(\w+)>(.*?)</\w+>"` will yield cleaner results. Or even `@"<(\w+)>(.*?)</\1>"`

Comment: That's true, first i did that, then i actually don't know how op will need the answer, it can be done as the op want on the fly i guess

Comment: Using Expresso to test those regexp values still only returns the tags and their contents not the text outside. is expresso giving incorrect results?

Comment: Tried this out. Unfortunately i'm wanting to use MatchCollection so i can get both the colour and the text. (I've named the two capture groups). However that still just returns the two results i original listed. I'm still struggling to get matches for the text outside of the tags.

Comment: if you loop through the array by using index increment  and see that the value contains angle bracket then you can also get the text instantly by just incrementing the index once more.... that should be simple. Moreover I kept the angle bracket intentionally otherwise, while looping through you dont  know the  difference between text and tag

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt Bingo that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try tinkering with xml you can try a solution like this one. We will use Linq. Try it online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J4zVMY

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        string response = @"Hello World <Red>This is some red text </Red> This is normal <Blue>This is blue text </Blue>";
        response = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><root>"+response+"</root>";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(response);

        // fill all node in a list of Text
        var colors = new List<Text>();
        foreach (var hashElement in doc.Descendants().Skip(1).Where(node => !node.IsEmpty))
        {
            var text = GetText(hashElement.PreviousNode);
            if (text != null)
                colors.Add(new Text(text));
            colors.Add(new Text(hashElement.Value.Trim(), hashElement.Name.ToString()));
        }

        // handle trailing content
        var lastText = GetText(doc.Descendants().Last().NextNode);
        if (lastText != null)
            colors.Add(new Text(lastText));

        // print
        foreach (var color in colors)
            Console.WriteLine($"{color.Color}: {color.Content}");
    }

    private static string GetText(XNode node)=> (node as XText)?.Value.Trim();

    public class Text
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }

        public Text(string content, string color = "Black")
        {
            Color = color;
            Content = content;
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
Black: Hello World
Red: This is some red text
Black: This is normal
Blue: This is blue text
```

caveat: Any help is welcome. My Linq-to-xml can be a bit rusty.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it's not xml i'm dealing with it's just a simple string passed into a method (from lua in that case, but i don't think that matters)

Comment: @user1412240 you can made it an xml easily : `@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><root>"+response+"</root>";`